# Google script - Create task in gmail from active cell in gsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have script which generate error in line 17
Maybe somebody could help me to solve this issue
I do not know how to fix it and make it working

```
ReferenceError: Gmail is not defined
createTaskFromCell  @ TaskCreator.gs:17
function createTaskFromCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellContent = activeCell.getValue();
  var taskTitle = cellContent;
  var taskDescription = "Please fill details";
  var taskDueDate = getNextWorkingDay();
  var task = {
    title: taskTitle,
    notes: taskDescription,
    due: taskDueDate,
  };
  var userId = 'me';
  var response = Gmail.Users.Tasks.insert(task, userId);
  Logger.log('Created task with ID: ' + response.id);
}
function getNextWorkingDay() {
  var today = new Date();
  var nextDay = new Date(today);
  while (!isWorkingDay(nextDay)) {
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return nextDay;
}
function isWorkingDay(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();
  return day !== 0 && day !== 6; // Exclude weekends (Saturday and Sunday)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ReferenceError: Gmail is not defined

Can be fixed by adding the gmail service

[image]

However I think your doing it wrong. You should be using [Tasks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks#add_task) not gmail

```
/**
 * Adds a task to a tasklist.
 * @param {string} taskListId The tasklist to add to.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/insert
 */
function addTask(taskListId) {
  // Task details with title and notes for inserting new task
  let task = {
    title: 'Pick up dry cleaning',
    notes: 'Remember to get this done!'
  };
  try {
    // Call insert method with taskDetails and taskListId to insert Task to specified tasklist.
    task = Tasks.Tasks.insert(task, taskListId);
    // Print the Task ID of created task.
    console.log('Task with ID "%s" was created.', task.id);
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception from Tasks.insert() of Task API
    console.log('Failed with an error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```